# echo in jquery doens't output as expected

Tags: php, jquery

I found on stackoverflow how to use a php variable in jquery, but on my test page, it simply isn't working:

```
$('#q').keyup(function(e) {
  var test = "<?php echo 'test123'; ?>";
  alert(test);
});
```

The code above outputs "" literally in the box where I want it to say "test123". I tried using single quotes instead of double, other small changes ... Didn't get it to work. Am I missing something?

The code above sits in a .js file which is linked in a .php page, which is (again) linked in my index.php file via require_once.

Comment: use var test = "test123"; or for dynamic you need js variable. In js file how you will able to write php code.

Comment: `The code above sits in a .js file` this is your problem - your PHP code will not be interpeted when it's inside a .JS file

Comment: Yes, but the next step is to use a value that's coming from a php class, this is just a reduced sample ...

Comment: @RuchishParikh the OP is trying to dynamically populate the variable from his PHP code, hardcoding in this case is obviously not an answer.

Comment: Can anyone explain all the downvotes for this question? What @RoryMcCrossan says would be helpful if it wasn't for the fact that we're told that the code outputs `""` not `<?php echo 'test123'; ?>`. Perhaps the actual output is `<?php echo 'test123'; ?>` in which case the answer is to make sure the .js file is parsed by php rather than just sent to the browser direct.

Comment: It might help to show a stripped-down version of `index.php` and the php page that includes the .js file.

Comment: @ChrisLear good point, the output should be the plain PHP code, not an empty string. Something odd is happening here.

Comment: @ChrisLear My guess is that it's obvious that the code provided does not match OPs real code...  not my downvotes though.

Comment: @Chris: my apologies, it does indeed output <?php ... I made an error when submitting the question.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid I agree with the downvotes. The solution provided by @C0dekid is probably what to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use **PHP** in javascript files (`.js`). Javascript and PHP are different languages. PHP works on the server-side and Javascript on the client-side.

You have to put this code in your `<head>` under the `jquery.js` file, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-jquery-file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#q').keyup(function(e) {
    var test = "<?php echo 'test123'; ?>";
    alert(test);
});
</script>
```

Also make sure your file extension ends with `.php`

*There is also an advanced solution for this, and that would be using the `header()` function. Save as `javascript.php` or someting Example:*

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
?>
$('#q').keyup(function(e) {
    var test = "<?php echo 'test123'; ?>";
    alert(test);
});
```

Then attach the file in your `<head>` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.php"></script>
```

Goodluck!